# Firebase validation newData.val().length

Tags: firebase, validation, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I can't figure out how to make sure invalid large data can be written to my Firebase project.

I have this data structure:

```
{
  "BotLevel" : 3,
  "CreateTime" : "2020-03-04T08:58:13.102305Z"
}
```

And this security rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "games": {

            "BotLevel": { ".validate": "true && newData.isNumber() && newData.val().length <= 10"},
                "CreateTime": { ".validate": true },

                "$other": { ".validate": false }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the rules I get error, even if I try to set `newData.val().length` to anything?
It validates fine without the `length` part, even `val()` validates to be below whatever x I try.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? verifying the number (`BotLevel` value) is less than a given value OR the **length** of the `BotLevel` value is less than a certain value.

Comment: I originally wanted to limit the length of my Data fields to make sure not to get hacked and have the database used to fill up with unsolicited data.

Comment: Since `BotLevel` is a number you need to check its value (which somehow correspond top a length check too, e.g. `< 1000  ===  length < 4`). The `length` property is for strings: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#length

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any documentation on this, but it seems you can use newData.val().length on strings ONLY and newData.val() on numbers.

So in my case I can use < "desired value" as a check for "spam" in numbers.

Comment: Please see the comment to your question. Also, you may add this precision to your initial question (click the edit link) instead of writing an answer.